# Black bar on IOS 7

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I have an iPad app. When I used it in iOS 5 or 6 its working fine and the UI also seems to be fine. But the same in iOS 7 a black bar on top, bottom, left and right of the screen appeared. Including on the splash screen.

I had tried it by hiding status bar of all views.But I cant fix the issue.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Can any one know what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me as a result of downloading the latest version of Xcode
and all I had to do was adjust the frame of my view as it was altered during the download. It's so simple I didn't even think to try it.

Answer (score -1):

How big are the bars? Is there any chance this is actually an iPhone retina app and this is iOS 7's new automatic scaling for the iPad's bigger display instead of the old '2x' mode?

Also, does it behave like this in the simulator and if so,  can you post simulator shots of it running under iOS 6 and iOS 7?

See here for what I mean : http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/07/ios-7-uses-retina-assets-of-iphone-only-apps-on-non-retina-ipad.html